# inverse of a point $p$ respect to the circle $|z-z_0 |= r$ in complex

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse

I was solving a problem to find the inverse of a point $p$ respect to the circle $|z-z_0|=r$. In my question I had to find inverse of $1+i$
w.r.t circle $|z+1-2i| = 2$. I applied the formula $q = z_0 + \frac{r^2}{\overline{p} - \overline{z_0}}$ where q is inverse of point $p$.
By this i got
$q = -1+2i + \frac{4}{1-i-(-1-2i)}$. But I am getting the wrong answer. Please help. Where I did wrong. Kindly give suggestions .
thanks

Comment: Before I compute, what is the right answer? Or do you not know that? What is the $1+2i$ doing in front?

Comment: right answer is $\frac{3+6i}{5}$. sorry it should be -1+2i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last term $\frac{4}{2+i}$ is $\frac{8-4i}{5}$. (I multiplied top and bottom by $2-i$.)

When we add $-1+2i$ we get $\frac{3+6i}{5}$. For $-1+2i=\frac{-5+10i}{5}$.

Comment: I got it.... Thanks for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: You are welcome. You had it right, though unsimplified.

Comment: yeah got it.... mistake was - skipping steps while solving properly.